# ExtentX with Selenium in C# throwing error

Tags: c#, mongodb, selenium, extent

I have configured my selenium tests in C# to report logs using Extent Reports and wanted to try the ExtentX version using MongoDB. I have set up ExtentX and MongoDB and they are running but the test fails with the following error...

"ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code, value cannot be null" at the following line in the teardown...

```
extent.EndTest(test);
```

I am specifying the mongo connection string via...

```
extent = new ExtentReports(reportPath, true); // create instance 
extent.X("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

The test runs fine when not specifying the mongo connection. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does your connection to mongo works ?

Comment: Hi, well mongo is running and I can connect with basic local host using Robomongo. Is there an easy way to check through visual studio?

Comment: See if this helps!! https://help.compose.com/docs/connecting-to-mongodb-classic

Comment: Yes that works via cmd line (mongo localhost:27017) and I can see my extentx database with (show dbs)

Comment: So still getting error originally stated even though I can connect to mongo

Comment: Do any of the log statements work with the test instance..  ex: test.Log(..) ? (When you have a mongo db connection)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132311/discussion-between-alex-and-prageeth-saravanan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to add AssignProject("") to the extent. Now it works and the ExtentX reports are populated. There is missing data but that's another issue.